# To deselect option in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I am using one button and giving the event as, when I click on that button then it will redirect to a webpage.
After that when I am coming back from the webpage and entering to the app again then also that button is selected.And it remains selected until I go to another webpage.
I want to deselect the button when I coming again to the app after webpage.

Can you please give me suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button Action Code call following method before going to webpage.

```
[sender setSelected:NO];
```